# Rhino mock calling the function that is mocked

Tags: rhino-mocks

Trying to mock a function with RhinoMock.

```
var repository = new Rhino.Mocks.MockRepository();
var classMock = repository.DynamicMock<Customer>();
Expect.Call(classMock.getCustomerAge("john")).Return(12);
```

The problem is that in the Expect.Call line it actually calls the function that it's supposed to mock. Am I doing something wrong? Isn't the purpose of mocking that you don't have to run the actual function?

```
public class AgeProvider
{
    private static Service _Service;
    private static string _User;

    public AgeProvider()
    {
    }

    public AgeProvider(ISession session, string authenticatedUser)
    {
        _Service = new Service(session);
        _user = authenticatedUser;
    }

    public int getCustomerAge(string userToSearch)
    {
        var user = _Service.FindUser(_user, userToSearch);

        return user.age;
    }

}
```

Simplified the class, where the function is that I'm trying to mock.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

is the method virtual?  I think you also need to use a partial mock if you are mocking a class rather than an interface.

Comment: can you update the question with the definition of the customer class?

Comment: Added the simplified class to the question.

Comment: thanks.  As this method is not virtual Rhino will not be able to mock it as it is, which I think is your problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably because you're using the older record/replay semantics.  Instead, use the new AAA (Arrange/Act/Assert) style:

```
classMock.Stub(r => r.getCustomerAge("john")).Return(12);
```

Comment: Whilst I think the suggestion to use the new style is a good one, I don't think the semantics should make any difference, you should be able to mock the virtual call either way, using the new or the old style